# Can I use @Autowired variable in @Bean method?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Is this valid or `bar` is `null` when getFoo is invoked?

```
@Configuration
class Config
{
    @Bean
    Foo getFoo()
    {
        return new Foo(bar);
    }

    @Autowired
    Bar bar;
}
```

Comment: I think it's faster to try it than wait for a answer, but my first thought is it should work because bar should be populated when the Config bean is created, just after the constructor is called.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that, all Autowired is doing is injecting Bar. Its not good way but you can do that.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on a few things: the type of the `@Bean`, the moment in the lifecycle of the beans involved that one of them is required, the context in which the `@Autowired` target bean is declared.

If you're not trying to do anything fancy, then, yes, it will work.